# Grub-pc installing error

Tags: apt, grub2, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub-pc installing error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25480/grub-pc-installing-error)

Trying to fix my apt-get upgrade, it always stopped at setting up grub-pc... I read somewhere that I should purge remove my grub2 and then reinstall it.

I did that and after lots of paying around i was able to remove it(wasn't such a smart move). Now i can't get it to install again.

I am trying `sudo apt-get install grub-pc`
and it just stops at `"Setting up grub-pc.."` and does nothing and because of this it isn't allowing me to do any kind of upgrade or install.. It asks me to `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
which again stops at setting up grub-pc

I think I need help and real soon. Thanks, I really appreciate any inputs here to get my system in place before the next reboot.