# No longer able to boot stuck in busybox shell

Tags: 11.04, boot

I've installed win 7 and ubuntu 11.04. After a storm killed the power. I'm unable to boot.

I'm stuck in the busybox shell (ash).

Here's what happens when I boot:

- Bios loads
- Grub displays option to load:

  - ubuntu
  - ubuntu recovery
  - memtest
  - another memtest option
  - win7
  - win 7 recovery
- I load Ubuntu

  - This cause it to load and i see no normal ubuntu screen just the busybox shell
  - I try loading ubuntu via `fsck -l` and it returns me a `/bin/sh` not found error.
- I load Windows 7 and I'm unable to boot. I get a blue screen of death
- I then load Ubuntu recovery and i don't have any luck either.

Any ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you cannot boot both windows 7 and ubuntu doesnt sound promising - maybe you've lost part or all of your partition information on your hard-drive or at a minimum, your master boot record has become corrupted.

Try booting via a USB or live CD - using gparted, do you see all your partitions?

Using nautilus (file manager) - can you mount your hard-drive and see your files?

**suggestion 1**

If everything appears to look ok - suggest reinstalling your grub using this [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25480/grub-pc-installing-error)

**suggestion 2**
If your partitions look ok, try running a fsck on each of the ext partitions displayed in gparted as per this [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44286/busybox-error-on-boot)

**suggestion 3**
If your partitions look a little screwy or non-existent then try a disk recovery procedure as per this [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30791/all-files-erased-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-alpha-3/31066#31066)

Comment: I ended up reformatting and reinstalling win 7 and ubuntu. I couldn't restore it. I even tried the systemrescuecd (http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) for linux distro's. I'll give you this answer nonetheless. They're good suggestions! Thanks.